# Test for visible in QUnit test of JQueryUI widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, qunit

*This may be obvious to everyone else but I didn't find it by searching, so posting both the question and one possible answer here.*

Background:

1. Custom JQuery UI widget using [widget factory](http://jqueryui.com/widget/)
2. In the widget, some elements get hidden or shown based on other data/options.
3. Creating unit tests to verify they are being shown/hidden correctly.
4. I thought that my unit tests could each create their own element in memory, similar to [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7621037/151212).

Stripped out the actual widget part from this example:

```
test( 'show/hide', 1, function() {
    var somecondition = true;

    var div = $( '<div/>' ).hide();
    if (somecondition) div.show();

    equal( somecondition, div.is( ":visible" ) );
});
```

The test fails because jQuery always reports `div.is( ":visible" )` as false. I thought that using `div.css('display') == 'none'` would be a workaround. Unfortunately, this worked in Chrome but not Firefox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that jQuery is smart enough to know that even if a particular element has **said** it's visible, it might not **actually** be visible if (for example):

1. It was never added to the DOM
2. The DOM element (or parent/grandparent/etc) it was appended to is not actually visible

So in order for the unit tests to work, I need to have a real div in the test harness html, attach the widget to it, and then call a destroy at the end.

```
test( 'show/hide', 1, function() {
    var somecondition = true;

    var div = $( '#someid' ).hide();
    if (somecondition) div.show();

    equal( somecondition, div.is( ":visible" ) );
});
```

I was hoping for a different approach (and maybe someone will come along and provide another answer), but I'm not very hopeful, seeing as this is the approach that JQueryUI uses in [their own QUnit tests](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/unit/autocomplete/autocomplete_methods.js):

```
test( "search, close", function() {
    //SNIP
    // Note the use of a real element here:
    element = $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: data,
        minLength: 0
    }),
    menu = element.autocomplete( "widget" );
    //SNIP
    ok( menu.is( ":visible" ), "menu is visible after search" );
    //SNIP
});
```